# How to use AWS WebRTC signed url in the frontend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, wss, pre-signed-url, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

The aws repo https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js provides the backend code to generate a presigned url.

I was able to log it and it looks like this (modified by adding/removing some characters to avoid misuse):

```
wss://v-7bd53a347.kinesisvideo.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-ChannelARN=arn%3Aaws%3Akinesisvideo%3Aap-south-1%3A3514502525359%3Achannel%2Fwebcam-signalling-channel-4%2F1637856477339&X-Amz-ClientId=U5PAWCWS5VE&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAVDVAVN2XSBEJVNOK%2F20211207%2Fap-south-1%2Fkinesisvideo%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211207T160335Z&X-Amz-Expires=299&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JopZ2luX2VjEND%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCmFwLXNvdXRoLTEiRzBFAiEA50TmitWwvooci6xG3i1M4jGzt7c7lfEu36TcdzOOFm8CIBNZLLDLB%2FDiBGIkU1PymctAcnobgu4WX%2F4KptvG%2BTOjKtMECKn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAhoMMzUxNDUwNTI1MzU5IgzlJEvF6NfKu43Rf70qpwRckEnOpVflPcE%2FvLtSXqgUCDI5qE5F9RUSpqtVKEA0Q6qPClsXw9IJMx2PWWQdgQ5I2uuMG1Ql1EH5DbY%2Fac0%2B%2BXWUJnPeHjDvpuNRk4J52YWAO02s4692U0EayCJsyxD57z5OKuQ8y9xkfjd60juMqJ8QUX1NsRgx10OJvxEbQh8Fou2N9qJeJokSrLOD6bCIRZdJQ%2FLzg6q7HdR5oqnNTMHNv7sJ0gmcxF7UhT0wS%2FuIcEtyNBo%2FyE1NI0ytgXVic6R7Pe4wSyzIn76W2x98I3OrbPa67vq3NzyJK1h%2F%2FqhfqNFPOaBP7eFGxcVWRPqz2VOknNtMD3b8QFZV2HwwnLBUXv2Dgp3Ez%2Fl%2F06hnAwHARStNtpP3ZX1maJE%2FBK52tRP%2BAWG1mv5wNodPWNAj%2B%2B04Obn91%2BjmAUc6ntXLWbZLUUuAtS8RSYDkX41ZA%2BnKTPZusBjh5vxW8A8fa3YKl33b4T9QT5eTWqNq9EXeI51Vd6mZsWh9kgEF768MSDn3hfTTIhFienuErO6N5wPWzOVp71aUgJS95Y2LTffOocP3CL3daCaYiEvzA%2FolDXwRzTqYRK6MwlqeAGjREmIoYjb11K4kU8mtHfDAKq5c1JA4cW719WBAoiQsxRO0egcFuskkGSCiAEaMAbg94eSnHpFLmPWYJwHj61eBU4JzIUsmzhxLF5x4MADUjxf1yOTRyx3FhIiO51gutW1fbgTt7z9lPn9szDXi76NBjqFAiE7AMy1zOl4hnXhjO60JRiKgHL0YuKsHJPAV02UmAdgf7lY%2Bl14ABncq4q1HSv%2BRKA2rr1ZM9JfgjMGHD0Xw9a8qFjN0RX5N%2FMw0F5nvVV9oGC8lYmT%2BLwW7DfyinSIA30SMzfXVfIEcGhEil900hoZMQZyvOWM4q7F%2Bye%2FN4%2FzS1RqMNHQGIT%2FdgOZkSJwyho6cpH1kEZXZMfhlWjOnTBjcqQzGYd9g9GLocDq8ZivrAKCtEM6yR%2Bh%2FsLhtGinqpsVFM%2BhaxK9G929tvlIQ3ZxA4GRAuTBepucoeVhmOwWv0f%2Fk82xjET%2FD5zVYvtMEpoU76aPal7pYNis98DspPB9ugrAw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Signature=8303b836351e231e9e7850cdd565a21073eaa4cb699b06d50c9e7f7e15a933e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

I am not able to understand how to use it in the frontend to view the video stream.
I have come across other comments seeking examples but there are no responses:

[How to use Kinesis Video Stream WebRTC SDK in the browser without providing credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920185/how-to-use-kinesis-video-stream-webrtc-sdk-in-the-browser-without-providing-cred/61934816#61934816)

Has anyone been able to use it?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for an answer, the signed url can be used while creating a signalling client in the front end code and can be used for connecting with AWS WebRTC Signalling service. You may find an example at below
https://blog.learningdollars.com/2021/05/09/aws-kinesis-video-stream-with-signed-url/

I implemented the above but was unable to see request from one front-end module to the other front-end module using AWS Kinesis WebRTC.